# Spring Data with MongoRepository - How can I find distinct combination of fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have following data in MongoDB

```
{
    "typeId": 1,
    "virtualType": 1
}, {

    "typeId": 1,
    "virtualType": 1
},
{

    "typeId": 1,
    "virtualType": 6
}, {

    "typeId": 2,
    "virtualType": 6
},
{
    "typeId": 2,
    "virtualType": 2
}
```

Using Spring data I need distinct combination of typeId and virtualType.
Someone please help me to find distinct combinations of typeId and virtualType

Comment: firstly, when you are using mongodb, there is no JPA involved. it wis spring-data-mongodb which does all the required things for you. secondly, how are you quering the database, yo you use repository or mongotemplate?

Comment: we are using both the way in our Project,repository and mongotemplate.

As of now I found mongo query which returning expected result,now trying implement it in spring-data-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could crack it in a following way

```
    db.getCollection('myDoc').aggregate([{ "$group": { "_id": { typeId":"$typeId","virtualType":"$virtualType"} }}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring JPA implementation for it using mongoTemplate

Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.group("typeId", "virtualType"));

List myDTO = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregate, "myDoc", myDTO.class).getMappedResults();